# Deploying LXC inside DRBD mount

Tags: mount, lxc

So I'm trying to deploy Ubuntu using LXC inside a DRBD mount.

First I've changed `/etc/lxc.conf` so `lxc.lxcpath` points to `/plesk` which is where I'll mount DRBD.

Then I created the machine with `lxc-create -t ubuntu -n plesk -B btrfs`.

Finally, I tried to mount and then launch the machine:

```
$ mount /dev/drbd0 /plesk
$ lxc-start -n plesk -F
```

And for that I get:

```
root@server1:/plesk# lxc-start -n plesk -F
lxc-start: conf.c: mount_rootfs: 798 No such file or directory - Failed to get real path for "/plesk/plesk/rootfs".
                                   lxc-start: conf.c: setup_rootfs: 1220 Failed to mount rootfs "/plesk/plesk/rootfs" onto "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lxc" with options "(null)".
                 lxc-start: conf.c: do_rootfs_setup: 3899 failed to setup rootfs for 'plesk'
            lxc-start: conf.c: lxc_setup: 3981 Error setting up rootfs mount after spawn
        lxc-start: start.c: do_start: 811 Failed to setup container "plesk".
                                                                            lxc-start: sync.c: __sync_wait: 57 An error occurred in another process (expected sequence number 3)
                lxc-start: start.c: __lxc_start: 1358 Failed to spawn container "plesk".
        lxc-start: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 366 The container failed to start.
lxc-start: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 370 Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority options.
```

If I `$ umount /plesk` then the machine launches just fine. How can I fix this?